# Лицензия на Windows + Windows Insider

Tags: windows, windows-10, лицензирование

Рассмотрим следующую последовательность действий:

1. Есть Windows 7
2. Дополнительно ставится Windows 10 Insider, естественно, с входом через live-аккаунт
3. Windows 7 обновляется до Windows 10
4. В Windows 10 создаётся локальный пользователь, live-аккаунт не используется

Получаются 2 системы:

- Windows 10 c лицензией после обновления
- Windows 10 Insider с бесконечной инсайдерсой (триальной) лицензией

Потом в инсайдерской десятке всё стало плохо работать и

5. Windows 10 Insider переустанавливается с DVD-диска без сохранения параметров
6. Осуществляется вход через тот же live-аккаунт

**Проблема**

7. Получена вторая Windows 10 без инсайдерского режима
8. Она автоматически использовала активацию десятки, полученной обновлением семёрки

**Вопросы**

1. Что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было законно пользоваться обеими десятками?
2. Не забанят ли ключ, если загрузиться в первую десятку?

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//superuser.com/q/1205233/724113)